# How can you get the RU/s consumed in a CosmosDB query in with pymongo?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm having an issue where I perform a query in the Azure portal and it consumes ~5 RU/s, but when I perform the same query in pymongo it throws "Request is Large", indicating that I don't have enough (we have 3000 RU/s provisioned).

How can I find out how many RU/s my pymongo query is consuming from within Python?

EDIT: Is there a way to find the total RU/s being used by the Cosmos (for example by other users?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [runCommand](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/) method in Pymongo:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()

client = MongoClient(
    'mongodb://***@***.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb')
db = client.testdb
coll = db.coll
result = coll.find_one()
print(coll.find_one())

result = db.command({"getLastRequestStatistics": 1})

print("Last RU Consume:", result["RequestCharge"])
```

***Output:***

[image]

Got this solution from this [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/10134) which is not mentioned from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/find-request-unit-charge#azure-cosmos-db-api-for-mongodb).

Comment: Perfect!

Do you know if there is a way to get the current RU/s (perhaps being used by other users in the same Cosmos)?

Comment: @A_toaster Thank you for your acception. I didn't found the feature and i'm afraid that the pymongo is built for native mongo db, not responsible for supporting cosmos DB Mongo API very nicely. (Anyway,i will try to find if any solution about your needs)

Comment: @A_toaster Besides, you could contact with Azure cosmos db team to submit your feedback.